# Push values from JSON object to array and use outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, axios

I am writing a axios JSON data call function and want to push values from my jJSON function to use outside of the function. Is there anyways I can do that?

My Code:

```
let website_names = `${api}`;
   axios.get(website_names, {
      cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
       api_requests.website_nm = c;
    })
  })
  .then(function(website_name) {
     website_name.data.forEach(d => {
     let yoyo = [];
     yoyo.push(d.element);
     console.log(yoyo);
    });
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert_error(error);
  });
```

This one gives me:

- {element: "Google"}
- {element: "Yahoo"}
- {element: "Facebook"}
- {element: "BuzzFeed"}
- {element: "Cnet"}

I need yoyo = `["Google", "Yahoo", "Facebook", "BuzzFeed", "Cnet"]`

But I also need to use `yoyo` outside of the axios function. I need the use of the array after it has been formed inside of axios.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` for this:

```js
const getWebsites = () => {
  let website_names = `${api}`;

  return axios
    .get(website_names, {
      cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
        api_requests.website_nm = c;
      })
    })
    .then(function(website_name) {
      return website_name.data.map(d => d.element);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      alert_error(error);
    });
};

getWebsites().then(yoyo => {
  //you now have the array
});
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I get that array outside the axios function? I want to use that array in other places of my code

Comment: updated my answer; if you functionalize your axios call and return the `Promise`, you can call `.then()` on it and the invoked function will have the array

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new array in each iteration thereby destroying the previous. The array should be initialized outside the `forEach` loop:

```
let yoyo = [];
website_name.data.forEach(d => {
   yoyo.push( d.element );
});
console.log(yoyo);
```

Comment: This works too but how do I use the array outside the function?

Comment: How about passing the array as a parameter to the function that uses it?

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am very confused about hoe to do this?

Comment: If `functionOne` is where you need `yoyo`, then just call `functionOne(yoyo)` when `yoyo` is available.